# Oracle SQL Procedure. What is the error here?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I wrote an PL/SQL procedure in Oracle APEX, and when I compile it, I get an error.
I do not understand what is the cause of the error. It looks to me that the sintaxis is correct.

Here is a screen capture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0XL6.png

This is the code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE imageBLOBtoHTML(  v_MimeType IN VARCHAR2 (255) := null,
                                              v_Size IN NUMBER := null,
                                              v_file_name IN VARCHAR2 (2000) := null,
                                              imageBLOB IN NOCOPY BLOB  := null )
AS
BEGIN

       --Generates HTML
       OWA_UTIL.mime_header (NVL (v_MimeType , 'application/octet'), FALSE);
       htp.p('Content-length: ' || v_Size );
       htp.p('Content-Disposition:  filename="' || SUBSTR(v_file_name , INSTR(v_file_name , '/') + 1) || '"');
       owa_util.http_header_close;

       --Stops generation of HTML
       wpg_docload.download_file(imageBLOB);
END imageBLOBtoHTML;
```

This is the error:

```
Compilation failed,line 1 (13:39:25)
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following: := . ) , @ % default character
```

Comment: Just use `v_MimeType IN VARCHAR2 := null` without size.

Comment: I think `:= null` is useless. You procedure will not work when any of your input parameter is NULL.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit Thank you! It seems to work, but now it refuses to accept the BLOB. If you write it as answer, I would be able to mark it.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit I wrote ":= null" because I misunderstood the compile error as demanding it. I have now deleted it.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit Have a reward https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjfpW4A4wtM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining my answer with the answer from XING it should be this one:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE imageBLOBtoHTML( v_MimeType IN VARCHAR2 := null,
                                             v_Size IN NUMBER,
                                             v_file_name IN VARCHAR2,
                                             imageBLOB IN OUT NOCOPY BLOB)
```

Permitting NULL for the other parameters (i.e. set NULL as default) does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Error is at line:

```
  imageBLOB IN NOCOPY BLOB  :=  null
```

you need to change it :

```
imageBLOB     IN OUT NOCOPY BLOB := ''
```

I would say as :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE imageBLOBtoHTML (
   v_MimeType    IN            VARCHAR2  := '',
   v_Size        IN            NUMBER := '',
   v_file_name   IN            VARCHAR2  := '',
   imageBLOB     IN OUT NOCOPY BLOB := '')
```

Comment: Thank you!. I wish I could mark multiple answers. Have a reward https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwsFy1EZupw

Comment: @bewe Np.. Wernfried Domscheit  is my firend so rewarding him is same as rewarding me.

Comment: You are disappointing me, `... IN VARCHAR2(xxx)` does not work.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Didnot notice that in hurry,,Corrected it